# How to use User managed identity to access Azure BatchClient programatically?

Tags: c#, azure-batch

We can typically use a `DefaultAzureCredential` object in `SecretClient` constructor to use managed identities to access a KeyVault.
I was looking for something similar where I can use the DefaultAzureCredential or some other mechanism through which I can instantiate an instance of `BatchClient` without having to provide a BatchAccountKey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was looking for something similar where I can use the DefaultAzureCredential or some other mechanism to instantiate an instance of `BatchClient` without having to provide a BatchAccountKey.

You can use the Defaultazurecredential with user-assigned managed identity in Azure batch using C#.

Here for a workaround, You can use the below code to list the pools in the Azure batch account using a user-assigned managed identity.

In my batch account, I have two pools:

[image]

**Code:**

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Azure.Batch;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Tolistpools
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Replace with your Batch account URL 
            string accountUrl = "your-batch-account-url";

            var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = "your-managed-identity-client-id" });
            AccessToken token = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://batch.core.windows.net/" }), new System.Threading.CancellationToken());
            BatchTokenCredentials cred = new BatchTokenCredentials(accountUrl, token.Token);
            using (BatchClient client = BatchClient.Open(cred))
            {
                // List the pools in the account
                var poolList = await client.PoolOperations.ListPools().ToListAsync();
                foreach (var pool in poolList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(pool.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(pool.State);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
123
Active
456
Active
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Venkatesan, Thanks for the brilliant answer. That works :)